# Everytime I restart my Digital Ocean server, .ssh/authorized_keys changes

Tags: ssh, vps

Every time I restart my Digital Ocean server manually from the website my .authorizedkeys get reset. It always has a value:

```
ssh-rsa   
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAm8glBB05kyIgRXCs8WuRwV5zLVU0LjzL1eFl70hIj0/raIl1RxCMrm6u7+fLjxEgoaCiuoNrL+gb+9Z6uBPhIdF3Q61WLuNB/nQ83S3o3d6gW9urkYU3/jKO1y7RZ+E/3u5GNrFsdMl4xaLatjcj7KSU6WJo4c90OSu0RhzZLS2jWKOLiWF3JSwoKTXouAfcDebhyt97D/HF/mZsIIG9wZVVZVoqFpm/RSZvsYvDdICy8hk3osVXW5rSw0vpB9uWBSQBfiJ5/eKZBeKSkJE8s3T75/NFrrr0n6A3h7fODsjUTIOYjOcFqAyrzdBG59eo441MaqB4nThGk+007IACZw== root@dedi10243.hostsailor.com
```

How to find who is doing it?

Comment: Please add some more information. What OS are you using exactly, what does the server do, is a management software like Plesk/Odin installed? And so on.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. Is it possible to find what all is modifying that file

Comment: Please update your answer with the asked information. If the file is changed on boot a management software may do this or your hoster made some settings to something like that.

Comment: What happens if you reboot the server with the shutdown command instead of shutting it down via the website?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `.authorized_keys` file is updated from the data you entered in the DigitalOcean control panel.

See the DigitalOcean documentation article [How To Configure SSH Key-Based Authentication on a Linux Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) for an explanation.

In the section [How to Embed your Public Key when Creating your Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server#how-to-embed-your-public-key-when-creating-your-server) you may find useful information, depending on your configuration.

Comment: Please give a brief overview what the article says regarding this question rather than just throwing in a link.

Comment: @Thorian I did.  That is the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I checked digital ocean. Its not from there.

Comment: Due to the issue occurring only after a reboot, there must be some setting that does that. Quick and dirty you could setup a cronjob that replaces the file with another file that contains the correct keys. But if it's not your DigitalOcean setting I don't really know what to look for. Especially as we still don't know the purpose of the system etc.